# Magento 2 - How to get current payment method which was selected

Tags: magento2, payment-methods

In Magento2, how to get current payment method which was selected on the overview checkout? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can get from the quote payment. You can try:

```
 /**
 * @var \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session $_checkoutSession
 */
$this->_checkoutSession->getQuote()->getPayment()->getMethod();
```

Answer (score 0):

Please refer following link for getting Payment methods.

http://blog.chapagain.com.np/magento-2-get-payment-methods-all-active-used/