# How to get selected payment method magento 2

Tags: magento2, onepage-checkout, payment-methods, payment-gateway, cash-on-delivery

This is my php file

```
public function getget(){

    $orderId = $this->getOrderId();

$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$order = $objectManager->create('Magento\Sales\Model\Order')->loadByIncrementId($orderId);
     $payment = $order->getPayment();
    $method = $payment->getMethodInstance();
    $methodTitle = $method->getTitle();
    return $methodTitle;
}
```

I need to get selected payment method by user but this shows payment method from order. I'm beginner.

Comment: Please can you clarify more your question so its easy understand.

Comment: On checkout page while selecting payment method I need to get which method is seleted. Above code shows paymentMethod of order I need checkoutSession order

Answer (score -2):

Please try this one

```
  /**
    * @var \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session $_checkoutSession
  */
   $session  = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session');

   $quote_id = $session->getQuoteId();

   $quote = Mage::getModel('sales/quote')->load($quote_id );

   $paymentcode = $quote->getPayment()->getMethodInstance()->getCode();
```

Comment: Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Magento\Checkout\Block\Mage' not found in /home/rkhomeappliances/public_html/vendor/magento/module-checkout/Block/Onepage.php

Comment: I'm getting this error

Comment: I need to get it may you help me I'm beginer

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/150595/magento-2-how-to-get-current-payment-method-which-was-selected

Is this the same problem which you are facing

Comment: $this->_checkoutSession->getQuote()->getPayment()->getMethod(); this returns white screen error

Comment: $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
 $cart = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart'); 
    $itemsCollection = $cart->getQuote();
    
    $it = $itemsCollection->getPayment();
    $iit = $it->getMethod();  How to get method name. getMethodTitle() and getTitle() doesnt wordks

Comment: This is M1 code while the question is asking for M2 solution.

Comment: @PYYick can you help me

Comment: I downvoted @TBIInfotech answer, not you. BTW Don't use Object Instance.  :)

Comment: Can this help you? https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/156933/get-payment-method-title-of-an-order